# Django comments custom user profile avatar

Tags: django, django-comments

I'm using [Ajax Comments System](https://github.com/dreidev/Comments) to render comments and the form 
and I have a custom user profile that include avatar field

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    avatar = ImageField('userprofile', default='avatars/default.png', upload_to="avatars" )
```

In a regular view i used to do:

```
from Profiles.models import UserProfile as Author
def BlogPost(request, slug):
    post_slug = posts.objects.get(slug=slug)
    author_avatar = Author.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=post_slug.author).id).avatar.url
    args = {
        'post_slug': post_slug,
        'author_avatar': author_avatar,
        'related': _related(post_slug.tags),
    }

    return render(request, "blog_post.html", args)
```

But Now I'm stack on getting every commentator avatar ... 
I need solution even if I used to modify the package or override it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time I was trying to override the views and adding some context but later I realized that the template args are in a template tag file some I copied the file into my project and I created a new tag that return the avatar

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_avatar(Profile, comment):
    return Profile.__class__.objects.get(user=comment.user.id).avatar.url 
# {% get_avatar UserProfile comment %}
```

I totally missed that template tags folder that's why it took me a while to solve it
**Update**
i met some manager and attribution errors this is my final custom tag 
if anyone have another solution post it

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_avatar(Profile, comment):
        user_id = comment.user.id
        try:
            return Profile.__class__.objects.get(user=user_id).user.avatar.url
        except:
            try:
                return Profile.objects.get(user=user_id).user.avatar.url
            except AttributeError:
                return UserProfile.objects.get(user=user_id).avatar.url
```

put this as hidden input before the avatar tag in your template to avoid referrer ajax server error ( for me this return the slug and for some reason without it the user avatar url will be sent as referrer )

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_url(comment):
    return str(comment.content_object).replace(' ', '_')
```